# Soft keyboard hides part of alertdialog

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

I have an alertDialog with a form on it. When I focus at an editText on that form the softkeyboard hides a part from my form. I tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" on my main activity's and form's layout but didn't worked. Any ideas?

Here is my main activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
...
...

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my form's layout:

```
<ScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true">
   <RelativeLayout 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#fff">
   ...
   ...
   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and here is how I create the alertDialog with the form on it (the layoutId param is the R.layout.form from above):

```
public static AlertDialog showPopupForm(Activity activity, int layoutId, OnClickListener submitAction){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    final View view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutId, null);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", submitAction);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    return dialog;
}
```

Thanks